# Why does AVG complain with Exploit Blackhat SEO type 1703

Tags: seo, html, blackhat

I installed "AVG internet security", opened a page in internet explorer, and AVG complains about "Exploit Blackhat SEO (type 1703)" for object name

[Action sports stock footage](http://www.actionsportsstockfootage.com/picturepage.html)

with no further details. (Note that I have not written this page. It seems to have been written in the distant past by several different persons.)

When I look at the html source code, I do not notice anything unusual. But then again, I do not know what I should look for or change to satisfy AVG.

I tried

[Sucuri SiteCheck](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/www.actionsportsstockfootage.com/picturepage.html)

with the results

```
Security report (No threats found):
check       Blacklisted:    No
check   Malware:    No
check   Malicious javascript:       No
check   Malicious iFrames:  No
check   Drive-By Downloads:     No
check       Anomaly detection:      No
check       IE-only attacks:        No
check   Suspicious redirections:        No
check   Spam:   No
```

The links toward the bottom of the HTML page such as `http://clips.actionsportsstockfootage.com/sdf_clip.php` link to a different server but at the same domain.

--

How do I solve the issue?

In the meantime, I have sent a report to AVG at [their AVG Incorrect page rating report page](http://www.avg.com/eu-en/page-rating-report).

Comment: Probably best to wait for AVG to reply to you directly from the report you sent them. I visited the website and did not get any warning of malware.

Comment: @tomsv, when I clicked on the [Sucuri link you provided](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/www.actionsportsstockfootage.com/picturepage.html), I saw "Warning: Malicious Code Detected on This Website!"

Answer (score 1):

AVG is likely picking up on links on the page that have historically spammy anchor text like:

- Blackjack
- Casinos
- Poker
- Roulette
- Slots

Your "gambling" category resembles the type of SEO spam that is often inserted into hacked sites.  Try removing that category and see if the error goes away.

If that is the problem, then you could try images rather than text for the words that are linked so that the scanner can't pick up on them.